# SharePoint navigation does not show subsite links for some users

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, global-navigation

I have a SharePoint site collection with many sites named,

- Finance
- Marketing
- Health
- and etc...

For some users it does not show some of these site links in the Global Navigation. Why is this? I am using SharePoint 2013.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure those users who cannot see the links are in those sites? Because SharePoint navigation are security trimmed. So the links won't display unless the users have access to them.